# Leaflet offset PNG tile layer coordinates

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to combine several hand-drawn map images into an interactive HTML feature using leaflet.

I've been trying to work up from the most basic code. To begin with I added three pictures at different zoom levels. I am still experimenting with that, but here's what the code looks like now:

```
  var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 10);

  L.tileLayer('Drawn/Pacific.png', 
              {tileSize: 800, noWrap: true, minZoom:10, maxZoom: 10}).addTo(map);
  L.tileLayer('Drawn/Hong Kong.png', 
              {tileSize: 800, noWrap: true, minZoom: 11, maxZoom: 11}).addTo(map);
  L.tileLayer('Drawn/Kowloon.png', 
              {tileSize: 800, noWrap: true, minZoom: 12, maxZoom: 12}).addTo(map);
```

How can I offset the starting coordinates of these layers so that they line (So that Hong Kong at zoom level 11 is actually where it should be in the Pacific Tile at zoom level 10)?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you have only 1 big image per "tile layer", so you would probably be interested in implementing your features as [Image Overlays](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#imageoverlay) instead:

> Used to load and display a single image over specific bounds of the map.

With Image Overlay, you can specify the geographical coordinates of your image, so that it is placed exactly where you want. You can adjust the relative coordinates of your 3 images, so that they line up as you need.

Comment: Thanks ghybs!

If I use image overlays, is it possible to also alter the image as I zoom? 

For example, "Pacific.png" is a large map that with little detail. I'd like "Hong Kong.png" to become visible as the user zooms into that area of the map. With image overlay, there doesn't seem to be any way to change the maximum and minimum zoom.

Comment: You can simply make up a listener on map's `"zoomend"` event and turn on/off the desired image overlays. Feel free to open a new question if you need help on that.